# Error (Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'GeoPoint'

Tags: flutter, serialization

JsonUnsupportedObjectError (Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'GeoPoint')

How can I solve this error? I think I my serialize of class was right but I the error continues so I dont know whats going on here.

**user**

```
@JsonSerializable()
class UserData {
  final String uid;
  late final String name;
  final Location location;

  UserData(
      {required this.uid,
      required this.name
      required this.location});

  factory UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$UserDataFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserDataToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Location {
  String locationName;
  @GeoPointSerializer()
  GeoPoint geoPoint;

  Location({required this.locationName, required this.geoPoint});

  factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$LocationFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$LocationToJson(this);
}

class GeoPointSerializer implements JsonConverter<GeoPoint, List<double>> {
  const GeoPointSerializer();

  @override
  GeoPoint fromJson(List<double> json) => GeoPoint(json[0], json[1]);

  @override
  List<double> toJson(GeoPoint geoPoint) =>
      [geoPoint.latitude, geoPoint.longitude];
}
```

**auth**

```
class AuthMethods with ChangeNotifier {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  
  Future<model.UserData> getUserDetails() async {
    User currentUser = _auth.currentUser!;

    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
        await _firestore.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).get();

    return model.UserData.fromJson(
        jsonDecode(jsonEncode(documentSnapshot.data())));
  }
 ...
```